# CanCanCan gem in Rails app: Preventing guests from accessing a specific model does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, cancancan, has-one

In a Rails app which uses JSONAPI::Resources and CanCanCan, I have a `Caption` model (`has_one :video`) and a `Video` model (`has_many :captions`).

I want to allow guests to only access those captions which belong to a *published* video: `can :read, Caption, video: { visible: true }`

However, this is not working. Guests can access all captions by visiting the `/captions` route. If I remove the above line, guests can't access any caption and receive 401 Unauthorized instead.

We have a few abilities defined in a similar way, and I just can't figure out what's the problem in this case. This specific ability definition seems not to be ignored, but interpreted in a wrong way. This variation also let's guest access all captions:

```
can :read, Caption do | caption |
  false
end
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: How do you distinguish between guests and authenticated users? Do you have a `can :manage, Caption` somewhere?

Comment: I have a rather complex `ability.rb` file with an `initialize` function at the top. This calls other functions such as `guest_actions` (which is what I'm working on right now), `user_actions`, etc. At the moment, I `return`from this funtion after calling `guest_actions`. There's no `can :manage` and no other `can :read, Caption` in this file.

Comment: I realized my problem is more general: Users should only be allowed to *add* captions to their own videos, but `can %i[create destroy], Caption, video: { creator: { id: person.id } }` causes a 403 unless I remove the condition on the video. This happens inside an `author_actions` method with a `person` argument. Using Byebug, I could verify that `person.id == video.creator.id`.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your problem, you can take a look at this page of the `cancancan` gem documentation :
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/debugging.md

You also have the gem `byebug` who is really helpful :
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/byebug/11.1.3

Comment: Thanks. We use Byebug, but placing *byebug* in the last code sample in my question did not have any effects when running the tests. I'll have a look at the documentation, I haven't seen the page you link to before.

Comment: The commands from the first two sections on that page output `true` for both `ability.can?(:read, Caption.first)` and `ability.can?(:index, Caption)`, and they output `false` when I comment out the line concerning `Caption`. The ability definition has an effect, but the condition on `Video` doesn't.